# Changing text in a text file via user input. Python

Tags: python

So I have this login in system where they can enter their favourite artist and genre. this gets saved to a text file. But know I need an option where they can change their favourite artist and genre. This is the code so far. The user information is stored in a text file all on the same line.

```
def registerUser():
 usrFile_write = open(textfile, "a")
 usrFile_write.write("\n" + username + ":" + password + ":" + date + ":" favArtist + ":" + favGenre + ":")
 print("New Account Created!\n")
 usrFile_write.close()
 Menu()
def change():
menu=input("Change account preferences? (y/n")
if menu == "yes":
    NewA=input("What is your new favorite artist...")
    NewG=input("What is your new favorite genre...")
    FavAG = open("user_DB.txt","w")
    FavAG.write (NewA)
    FavAG.write ("\n")
    FavAG.write (NewG)
    FavAG.close()
```

Comment: And what's the issue here?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question, or if there even is one, really.

Comment: @AmitTripathi hi. could you email me please I would really like your help, bossanbar324@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should always use `with` statements when working with files. The benefits of this are well documented. So this:

```
usrFile_write = open(textfile, "a")
usrFile_write.write("\n" + username + ":" + password + ":" + date + ":" favArtist + ":" + favGenre + ":")
print("New Account Created!\n")
usrFile_write.close()
```

Becomes:

```
with open(textfile, "a") as usrFile:
    usrFile.write("\n" + username + ":" + password + ":" + date + ":" favArtist + ":" + favGenre + ":")
    print("New Account Created!\n")
```

Now, working in a plain text file, you can't really edit specific lines. In order to update an existing user entry, you will have to delete the existing entry and create a new one in its place. This requires reading through the file and re-writing the whole thing, except for the specific line. You can put this into a generalized `deleteUser` function for re-use later on:

```
def deleteUser(username):
    with open(textfile, "r") as usrFile:
        lines = usrFile.readlines()
    with open(textfile, "w") as usrFile:
        for line in lines:
            if line.split(":")[0] != username:
                usrFile.write(line)
```

Then, to modify a user, you delete their entry and then create a new one with the new information.

This ought to cover you for now. I recommend looking into using a database like sqlite in the long term, this job is much better suited for it.

Comment: Hi could you email me please.  bossanbar324@gmail.com. I could really use your help.